# TypeError cannot set property 'size of' undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, file-upload, undefined

Trying to get the size of a file when the user uploads file.
When user clicks on the browse button to upload file, 
but instead clicks the cancel button. 
The filesize type throws an error of undefined.

I tried to use typeof to test condition of filesize is
undefined but it does not work. Need help to catch error.

```
$('#fileupload-image').change(function() {
    $('#select_file').hide();
    $('#upload_image_button').slideDown('fast');
    var filename = $(this).val();

    if(typeof this.files[0].size == 'undefined')
    {
        this.files[0].size = '';
    }
    else 
    {
        var filesize = this.files[0].size;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another possibility:

```
var filesize = (this.files.length && this.files[0].size) || '';
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't think you actually want to be setting `this.files[0].size = '';`.

Here's one possibility, using a try/catch to forget all about type checking:

```
var filesize = '';
try {
    filesize = this.files[0].size;
}
catch {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a this.files.length > 0 check instead of checking to see if it is undefined.  Also, if you're checking to see if it's undefined you wouldn't want to be using single quotes either.